# How to get current td value from table onclick?

Tags: javascript

I want value of first td onclick whenever i click on any of the table row. I am using jquery below code to create table rows dynamic.
This data is javascript array of key value pairs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.each(Data, function(key, value) {
      $('#idforappend').append('<tr class="tr_use"><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+value+'</td></tr>');
      });
});
```

Now when i click on any row i want first td value only that row. How can we do that please help.

Comment: give each `td`  element an unique ID, turn it to an `button` then add `onClick` property or `addEventListener`

Comment: Read up about listening to the `click` event bubbling up using the `.on()` method: https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dynamic table using jS. when clicking on the row it will console 1st TD value only.

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

createTable([["row 1, cell 1", "row 1, cell 2"], ["row 2, cell 1", "row 2, cell 2"]]);
jQuery('tr').on('click', function(){
console.log(jQuery(this).find('td').first().text());
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the solution thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
  $(".btnSelect").on('click',function(){
     var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
     var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
  });
});
```

Comment: @Amit, please do not edit other ppls answer to add what you used

Comment: Okay mplungjan. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just add the same `onClick` handler on each row when you are creating your table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.each(Data, function(key, value) {
      $('#idforappend').append('<tr class="tr_use" onClick="handle(event)"><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+value+'</td></tr>');
      });
});
```

Your resultant table should be something similar to the below table

```
<table>
<tr  onClick="handle(event)">
  <td>key1</td>
  <td>value1</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="handle(event)">
  <td>key2</td>
  <td>value2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Your event handler

```
function handle(event){
console.log(event.currentTarget.children[0].textContent);

}
```